# remove time check in php script

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a php script in prestashop that (should) downloads an xml file and then begin the import proccess. The script checks if the file that was downloaded the last time matches the time in the database entry and if they do not match the it downloads the new xml. This whole thing does not work as it should mainly because the whole if command is wrong. (Normaly it should first download the file and then check it the time mathces). Anyway this is all not required since the file is small. So instead I need to remove this if statement and download the file anyway replacing the previous downloaded file.
Can anyone please help me remove the if command that checks the date?

This is the script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
//ini_set('memory_limit', '812M');
set_time_limit(0);

include_once realpath(__DIR__.'/../../')."/config/config.inc.php";
include_once realpath(__DIR__)."/XmlFeedImporter.php";
if( Configuration :: get('CRONRUN_STATUS') && Configuration :: get('PRODUCTXML_URL')){
    $remoteXmlFile = Configuration :: get('PRODUCTXML_URL');
    $url_parts = parse_url($remoteXmlFile);
    $isCLI = ( php_sapi_name() == 'cli' );
    if( $isCLI){
        // For live
        $server_host = $url_parts['host'];
        $server_root = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/';
    } else {
        $server_host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $server_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/';    
    }

    $outputLocalCsv = _PS_DOWNLOAD_DIR_.'products_output_'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv';
    $objXmlFeedImporter = new XmlFeedImporter();

    if(strpos($remoteXmlFile,$server_host) === false){
        // CHeck whether same remote file was download or not ?
        if (((int)Configuration :: get('PRODUCTXML_DOWNLOAD_DATE') && (int)Configuration :: get('PRODUCTXML_UPDATE_TIME')) && ((int)Configuration :: get('PRODUCTXML_DOWNLOAD_DATE') > (int)Configuration :: get('PRODUCTXML_UPDATE_TIME'))) {
            $inputLocalXml = _PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.'products_input_'.date('Y-m-d', Configuration :: get('PRODUCTXML_DOWNLOAD_DATE')).'.xml';
        } else {
            $time = time();
            $inputLocalXml = _PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.'products_input_'.date('Y-m-d', $time).'.xml';
            $downloadedBytes = $objXmlFeedImporter->downloadRemoteFile($remoteXmlFile, $inputLocalXml);
            Configuration :: updateValue('PRODUCTXML_DOWNLOAD_DATE', $time);

            if($downloadedBytes == 0){
                d('Nothing was downloaded from '.$remoteXmlFile.' !!');
            }
        }
    } else {
        $file_parts = explode($server_host, $remoteXmlFile);
        if( $server_host == 'localhost'){
            $server_root = str_replace(DS.'my-presta','',$server_root);
        }
        $inputLocalXml = $server_root.trim($file_parts[1],'/');
    }
    //d($inputLocalXml);
    $objXmlFeedImporter->setInputFile($inputLocalXml);
    // Get products in a csv  
    if(Configuration :: get('CREATE_XML2CSV')){
        $objXmlFeedImporter->setOutputFile($outputLocalCsv);   
    }
    //$objXmlFeedImporter->_justCount = true; // just count products
    //$objXmlFeedImporter->_dump = true; // print product data
    try{
        $objXmlFeedImporter->runParser(); // run parser
    } catch(Exception $e){
        // Send Email
        print_r($e);
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is without that check:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
//ini_set('memory_limit', '812M');
set_time_limit(0);

include_once realpath(__DIR__.'/../../')."/config/config.inc.php";
include_once realpath(__DIR__)."/XmlFeedImporter.php";
if( Configuration :: get('CRONRUN_STATUS') && Configuration :: get('PRODUCTXML_URL')){
    $remoteXmlFile = Configuration :: get('PRODUCTXML_URL');
    $url_parts = parse_url($remoteXmlFile);
    $isCLI = ( php_sapi_name() == 'cli' );
    if( $isCLI){
        // For live
        $server_host = $url_parts['host'];
        $server_root = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/';
    } else {
        $server_host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $server_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/';    
    }

    $outputLocalCsv = _PS_DOWNLOAD_DIR_.'products_output_'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv';
    $objXmlFeedImporter = new XmlFeedImporter();

    if(strpos($remoteXmlFile,$server_host) === false){
        // CHeck whether same remote file was download or not ?
        $time = time();
        $inputLocalXml = _PS_UPLOAD_DIR_.'products_input_'.date('Y-m-d', $time).'.xml';

    } else {
        $file_parts = explode($server_host, $remoteXmlFile);
        if( $server_host == 'localhost'){
            $server_root = str_replace(DS.'my-presta','',$server_root);
        }
        $inputLocalXml = $server_root.trim($file_parts[1],'/');
    }

    $downloadedBytes = $objXmlFeedImporter->downloadRemoteFile($remoteXmlFile, $inputLocalXml);
    Configuration :: updateValue('PRODUCTXML_DOWNLOAD_DATE', $time);
    if($downloadedBytes == 0){
             d('Nothing was downloaded from '.$remoteXmlFile.' !!');
        }

    //d($inputLocalXml);
    $objXmlFeedImporter->setInputFile($inputLocalXml);
    // Get products in a csv  
    if(Configuration :: get('CREATE_XML2CSV')){
        $objXmlFeedImporter->setOutputFile($outputLocalCsv);   
    }
    //$objXmlFeedImporter->_justCount = true; // just count products
    //$objXmlFeedImporter->_dump = true; // print product data
    try{
        $objXmlFeedImporter->runParser(); // run parser
    } catch(Exception $e){
        // Send Email
        print_r($e);
    }

}
?>
```

This seems to be the if you were talking about:

```
if (((int)Configuration :: get('PRODUCTXML_DOWNLOAD_DATE') && (int)Configuration :: get('PRODUCTXML_UPDATE_TIME')) && ((int)Configuration :: get('PRODUCTXML_DOWNLOAD_DATE') > (int)Configuration :: get('PRODUCTXML_UPDATE_TIME')))
```

Comment: Hi, This was what I removed fist also but after removing the script does not download the file at all

Comment: i've edited, and placed the download function outside the if clause. maybe your strpos($remoteXmlFile,$server_host) didn't evaluate to false, and the else clause didn't had the downloadRemoteFile.